# Why am I not able to list all EC2 attributes through my python boto3 code?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

```
import boto3
import csv
import pprint

ec2_cli=boto3.client(service_name='ec2')   #creating a ec2_cli object with client session
aws_regions = ec2_cli.describe_regions()['Regions']  
all_aws_regions = []
for each_region in aws_regions:
    #print(each_region['RegionName'])
    all_aws_regions.append(each_region['RegionName'])

#print (all_aws_regions)

file_open = open('ec2_inventory.csv', 'w', newline='')
data_obj=csv.writer(file_open)
data_obj.writerow(["S.no", "InstanceID", "ImageID", "Instance Lifecycle", "Instance Type", "Private DNS Name", "Private IP Address", "Root Device Name", "Root Device Type", "VPC ID"])

count = 1
for each_region in all_aws_regions:
    ec2_resource = boto3.resource(service_name='ec2', region_name = each_region)
    for each_inst_in_reg in ec2_resource.instances.all():
        #print (count,each_inst_in_reg.instance_id, each_inst_in_reg.`block_device_mapping.device_name`, each_inst_in_reg.block_device_mapping.status, each_inst_in_reg.block_device_mapping.volume_id, each_inst_in_reg.dns_name, each_inst_in_reg.image_id, each_inst_in_reg.instance_lifecycle, each_inst_in_reg.instance_state_name, each_inst_in_reg.instance_type, each_inst_in_reg.ip_address, each_inst_in_reg.owner_id, each_inst_in_reg.private_dns_name, each_inst_in_reg.private_ip_address, each_inst_in_reg.root_device_name, each_inst_in_reg.root_device_type, each_inst_in_reg.vpc_id, each_inst_in_reg.tag_key)
        data_obj.writerow([count,each_inst_in_reg.instance_id, each_inst_in_reg.image_id, each_inst_in_reg.instance_lifecycle, each_inst_in_reg.instance_type, each_inst_in_reg.private_dns_name, each_inst_in_reg.private_ip_address, each_inst_in_reg.root_device_name, each_inst_in_reg.root_device_type, each_inst_in_reg.vpc_id])
        count+=1

file_open.close()
```

I am unable to return the values of block_device_mapping.device_name, block_device_mapping.device_status in the excel file. Can some one advice what is that I am missing. I can see in the instances.all() has following attributes that can be called: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to"? Is there an error? Are there unexpected values in `block_device_mapping`?

Answer (score 2):

The `ec2_resource.instances.all()` command is returning a *list* of `ec2.Instance`.

In looking at the boto3 documentation for EC2:

- The `ec2.Instance` object includes an attribute called `block_device_mappings` (note that it is plural)
- That attribute is a *list* that contains entries for `DeviceName` and an `Ebs` dictionary
- The `Ebs` dictionary contains an entry called `Status`

Therefore, there might be **multiple block devices** attached to an Amazon EC2 instance. This does not map well to a CSV file that expects the same number of columns for each row -- for example, think about what information it should contain if there are multiple Amazon EBS volumes attached to the EC2 instance.

To access the Name and Status fields, you could either loop through each entry in `block_device_mappings`, or you could make an assumption that you only want information about the *first* volume that is attached.

To obtain information about the *first* volume, you could simply use:

```
each_inst_in_reg.block_device_mappings[0].DeviceName
each_inst_in_reg.block_device_mappings[0].Ebs['Status']
```

To loop through *each* volume, you could use:

```py
for volume in each_inst_in_reg.block_device_mappings:
  name = volume.DeviceName
  status = volume.Ebs['Status']
```

Comment: I actually removed all the CSV file lines and still the code is not running, here is the below error:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'device_name'

And I checked https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html 
there are attributes like: block-device-mapping.device-name, block-device-mapping.status etc...

Comment: The attribute is `DeviceName`, not `device_name`. I recommend you [consult the documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Instance.block_device_mappings) when seeking field names.